# 3D costmap as obstacle for MoveIt!

Tags: ros, moveit, voxel-grid, 2dcostmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear Ros Users,

I am using MoveIt for controlling a robotic arm

Is there a way to use a 3D grid as costmap as obstacle for MoveIT planner?
Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/249263/3d-costmap-as-obstacle-for-moveit!/) by [Rahndall](https://answers.ros.org/users/3415/rahndall/) on ROS Answers with karma: 133 on 2016-12-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

While not entirely identical to the way the 2DCostmap works, the [Octomap](http://wiki.ros.org/octomap) is probably the closest alternative for 3D. Usually, the Octomap is fed by a depth camera, but it is also possible to specify the occupied voxels in any other way. The occupied voxels are then treated as collision obstacles, so MoveIt! planners will avoid any collisions with these voxels.

Have a look at [this](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/moveit_tutorials/html/doc/pr2_tutorials/planning/src/doc/perception_configuration.html) tutorial to see how it is used with a depth camera. This will also function for any other node publishing `sensor_msgs/PointCloud2` messages on the input topic.

---

Originally posted by [rbbg](https://answers.ros.org/users/26757/rbbg/) with karma: 1823 on 2016-12-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rahndall](https://answers.ros.org/users/3415/rahndall/) on 2016-12-02**:
This absolutely answers to my (probably newbie) question. Thank you!